# How do I create two outputs for when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, button

My objective is to create nine buttons in a 3-by-3 grid using HTML. Then, using JavaScript, I want to program the buttons so when each button is clicked, there are two outputs.

The outputs are a horizontal value left or right and a vertical value up or down. My problem is connecting the buttons to an output when they are clicked – how can I do that?

Comment: describe your problem in code you've tried

Comment: Could you please share what you are trying to do?

Comment: My objective is to create 9 buttons in a 3*3 grid using html. Then using javascript, program the buttons so when each button in clicked there is two outputs. The outputs are a horizontal value left or right and a vertical value up or down. My problem is connecting the buttons to an output when they are clicked. i just started javascript and the syntax is still a mystery to me.

Comment: did you google how to handle a JavaScript click event, and how to use Javascript to insert content into the page? There are literally hundreds of examples of this kind of thing out there already. No need for us to re-invent the wheel. If you actually tried something and then encountered an error, then that's different - edit the question to include your code and a description of the problem, and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are html elements to fire an event. The event handler performs the necessary steps that you want to perform upon button click. The event handler you can create differently.

**Through handler attribute in HTML tag :** 
For an input type button it would be like,

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="click!!!"/>
```

and you have to define `myFunction()` function inside the script tag at the end of body element. Here "onclick" is the handler attribute.

**Separate JavaScript file:**
Here you will create the input element with button type in your html file such as,

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="click!!!"/>
```

and then in your ".js" file you can attach event handler to your input element of button type in two ways such as,

**a. Named function:**

```
function myFunction()
{
//perform whatever you want to do on button click
}
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",myFunction());`
```

**b. Through anonymous functionality**

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",function({
//perform whatever you want to do on button clicked
});
```

So the take away is, you always have to attach a functionality for the input element if you want to perform an event on it. This you can do in different ways as described above.